# Export to excel with jquery ajax and servlet

Tags: jquery, ajax, excel, servlets

I am facing issues while writing code to export data(coming from server) to excel file. I wrote simple code to do so.

ajax call to   call my export to excel servlet .

```
 $.ajax({
                url : "http://localhost:8800/project/abc/export", 
                type: "POST",
                data : data,          
                dataType: "text",
               /* contentType: "application/vnd.ms-excel",*/
                success : function(data, text_status, XMLHttpRequest) {
                    console.log("export done");         
                },
                error : function(XMLHttpRequest, text_status, error) {
                    console.log("error"+text_status+":::"+error);
                }
            });
```

Below is my Servlet code :

```
@Path("/abc")
public class Resource {


    @POST
    @Path("/export")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces("application/vnd.ms-excel")
    public Response exportResults(@Context HttpServletRequest req,@Context HttpServletResponse resp) {
        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("results");
        Row header = sheet.createRow(0);
        header.createCell(0).setCellValue("tttttt");        
        File f =new File("new-excel-file.xls");     
        FileOutputStream fos;
        ResponseBuilder response = null ;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
             wb.write(fos);  
             response= Response.ok((Object) f);

                fos.close(); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           

        response.header("Content-Disposition",
                "attachment; filename=new-excel-file.xls");
         response.header("Content-Type","application/octet-stream"); 
        return response.build();
    }

}
```

I am expecting a pop up asking to save file after my ajax call is done.I can see data getting printed after ajax call but no pop up is coming. Could someone help me with this.

My ajax request is POST request, so I can't use window.location= url.